# .txt to .csv via rename file extension losses lines

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[EXCEL] I have about 900 rows and about 23 columns on a sheet and I saved it as Tab Delimited and closed. But when I rename the file extension to .csv it losses some of its line, in this case about 28 of them. What could possibly be wrong?

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean changing file extension in windows explorer (/ total commander / ... ) while the file is closed? If yes, than that question isn't related to Excel, neither to Worksheetfunction. Changing the file extension is not the right way, you need to open the file (e.g. in Excel) and save it with the new extension.

Comment: I suggested that too but that's how they specifically asked on how to save file and upload it on their system. I found some solution from other thread on adding:

sep=;

inside A1 and it viola. It actually does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your regional settings, Excel will process files with the .csv extension differently. This is because "CSV" doesn't have an official standard. In most cases, when opening a .csv file, Excel will expect comma, or semicolon as a separator, never a Tab.

When opening flat-text data (like .csv), you should never just double-click and expect Excel to correctly guess the separator, delimiter, encapsulation and encoding. You will break your data.

I have written an in depth piece about this [over here](https://theonemanitdepartment.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/the-absolute-minimum-everyone-working-with-data-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-file-types-encoding-delimiters-and-data-types-no-excuses/) that goes over all the details that you realy realy should be aware about...

In your specific case, the problem is not that the lines have disappeared, the problem is that Excel is not displaying them in the way you expect them to be displayed. If you would open your txt/csv file using a text editor, I am sure you will find all your data is there. The solution to your problem is learning how to [import csv files into Excel](https://www.google.be/search?safe=off&q=importing%20csv%20into%20excel&cad=h).

Comment: I think it has something to do with regional setting. Raw file was from another country and I formatted the same file to meet the requirement and saved it as what I have mentioned above. Thanks for pointing this one out to me as I was pretty clueless to these things. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should not rename the file to csv, you should open the file and use "Save as" and there you select csv.

Also it does not make sense that renaming the file is changing the file inside, maybe the problem is the editor you are using to open it. One important thing is that each Operative System (windows, osx and linux) have different characters to end a line, maybe the editor and the end of line are causing the problem).

Use an editor to watch which is or are the characters at the end of line.